# Javascript - Go Back Page List

Tags: javascript

Current working code to go back one page:

```
onclick="location.href=document.referrer; return false;
```

This code allows me to go back by one page only. Are there any code snippets that would allow to go back multiple pages similar to a browser's back button?

I understand there is a **go()** method to use with **window.history.go(-i)** but that doesn't solve the need. I am hoping to show a list of pages visited for a user to click on the desired page. This is similar functionality to a browser's back button.

In essence, trying to go back sequentially instead of jumping back x number of pages.

Thanks in advance for all of your inputs.

Comment: You'll have to create the menu you want on your own, but history api is the right tool for this job.  Generate the links you want with it, display them, and you should be there.

Comment: "I am hoping to show a list of pages visited for a user to click on the desired page" You can't do this, this would be a security issue. What the user has been visiting is none of your website's business, especially if the history is not part of your site. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history  But anyway why do you need to replicate what the browser can already do?

Comment: The history stack can't be reached. I think that you cant achive your goal..